# Partition of regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a $d$-regular graph, drawn randomly using the configuration model. The number of vertices is $|V| = n$.

Under this model, we know that the graph looks tree-like locally. In other words, we know that if $X_r$ were the number of vertices in $G$ whose $r$-neighborhood is not a tree, then

$\mathbb{E}[X_r] = o(n)$ for $r \leq \frac{\log_{d-1}n}{2}$.

Only a constant fraction of vertices contain cycles in their $r$-neighborhoods.

See [here](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXooW7yObWAhXCrRoKHZCvA6UQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.mit.edu%2F~mustazee%2Fcourses%2FS16%2Fbeamertemp.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0BK3IZcTZdosL_bnP0yT0Z) for instance. (Slide 19 of lecture notes from a course at MIT)

I would like to know whether I can partition this graph in such a way that each partition is a tree, the partitions do not overlap and together constitute the entire graph? If not, can I do something close to this or perhaps approximate the original graph this way?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any requirements on the number of parts in the partition? Or can I just partition the graph into $\frac12 nd$ trees consisting of a single edge?

Comment: I'd like each partition to be a tree of depth log(n)-ish